# dual boot windows 10 and Ubuntu WiFi sometimes not working and sometimes work

Tags: networking, dual-boot, drivers, wireless, windows-10

1. when WiFi adapter removed , it removed from both (Ubuntu and Windows)
2. when it came back it came for both

- i bought a new laptop MSI GF65 Thin
- it came with original windows 10
- after using it for sometime (about few hours) WiFi driver deleted by itself !!
- i though this is a problem with the driver or windows
- i installed Ubuntu alongside windows 10
- i found that WiFi working very well but .....
- after some days (about 2 days) WiFi adapter begin to deleted from Ubuntu too
- when i keep my laptop for a while (full night) i found that WiFi working well on both Ubuntu and windows 10

i think it is a hardware problem !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

help please

Comment: Sounds like you might have to check the connection between the wifi card and motherboard

Comment: @Jeremy31 how can i do this

Comment: There is likely an access panel on the bottom of the laptop that can be removed to check the wifi.  There is a youtube video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=a92uK0skxvs  dont remove the antennas from the wifi as they are fragile on those

Comment: I can't play with hardware . It is dangerous. Thanks anyway